# How to display multiple boxplots for different features against the same y axis

Tags: python

I am trying to figure out how to simply plot create a number of boxplots that look at different X axis in relation to a consistent Y value.

For example, take this telecom dataset: https://www.kaggle.com/blastchar/telco-customer-churn

Is there a way I can look at the Tenure across all categorical variables without specifically manually having to input a different x?

By that I mean like this...

```
churned.boxplot('tenure', by='Partner')
churned.boxplot('tenure', by='SeniorCitizen')
```

etc...

I have tried using Catplot, but to my understanding, You can't look at different X values.

Answer (score 0):

I dont use seaborn but I made a small script below that might help you, just using plotly instead of seaborn (you might like plotly better anyways :) ) 
[notebook link](https://www.kaggle.com/datasciencetony/kernel84a81e0b19)

```
from plotly import tools
import plotly.offline as pyo
from plotly.offline import init_notebook_mode
import plotly.figure_factory as ff
import plotly.graph_objs as go
init_notebook_mode(connected=True)
columns = ['gender', 'SeniorCitizen', 'Partner', 'Dependents']
plot_y = []
names = []
for i in columns:
    for x in data[i].unique():
        plot_y.append(data[data[i]==x].tenure.sum())
        names.append("{}and{}".format(i,x))
trace = [go.Bar(x=names,
               y=plot_y)]
pyo.iplot(trace)
```